# Python: Executing a function when it is stored in a variable

Tags: python, function

I'm trying to activate a function which is stored inside a variable.
I've tried to use "lambda:" like this:

```
def test():
    print("this works")

var = test()
lambda: var
```

---

It doesn't work. Is there any way to do that without doing anything complex? If not I don't mind hearing the complex way.

---

Edit:

When I posted this I meant that I wanted parameters in the function for example if you use:

```
def test(thing):
    print(thing)

var = test
var()
```

Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You stored the **result** of the function, not the function itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use the parentheses to call the function. When you assign, you don't need the parentheses.

```
>>> def test():
...     print("this works")
...
>>> var = test
>>> var()
this works
```